# Kmeans and SAS: proc fastclus how to get outseed, converge and strict

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, k-means

this is the sas code which i want to replicate in R,

```
proc fastclus data = in.stores_standard
maxclusters = 20
outseed= in.out_seed
maxiter = 1000
converge = 0 
strict=5.0; 
var storesize sales_per_sqft sales_per_visits tothhsinta;
id store_nbr;
run;
```

my attempt:

```
library(amap)
set.seed(1)
kmeans_object=Kmeans(stores_standard, 20, iter.max = 1000, nstart = 1, method = c("euclidean"))
p=do.call(rbind, kmeans_object)
```

What am unable to achieve:
1) run kmeans on these parameters only: storesize,sales_per_sqft,sales_per_visits, tothhsinta

2) id on store_nbr

3) outseed function in R

Thanks!

Comment: For those R users that never used SAS, perhaps you could explain what "id on store_nbr" and "outseed function in R" actually mean?

Comment: Sorry about that Gavin,
1) store_nbr is my primary key, so i dont want clustering to be done on this var, but keep it nevertheless because when i will i have the final output each store_nbr will be having a CLUSTER_nbr assigned to it, in this case : 1 to 20
2) outseed function will create a dataset on which we can run proc fastclus again so that to get a new seed file on which fastclus is run again.
this is done if the data set is large or contains outliers, to make a preliminary PROC FASTCLUS run with a large number of clusters, perhaps 20 to 100. we use MAXITER=0 and OUTSEED=SAS-data-set.

Comment: @GavinSimpson could you please explain what is the function of nstart and how is it different from iter.max? thanks!

Comment: Did you read `?Kmeans`. `nstart` controls the number of random starts **if** the `centers` argument is a numeric (i.e. number of clusters). `iter.max` is the maximum number of iterations of the algorithm (i.e. how many times `Kmeans()` tries to update the current cluster solution.

Comment: Yes @GavinSimpson, I read that but couldn't grasp much from the help file, but i did stumble across this:

nstart (int) – If greater than one, nstart runs of the clustering algorithm will be executed, returning the clustering with the best (lowest) score.

and also the fact that I am getting better clusters if higher the nstart value.

So with different set.seed() values i was getting different distribution of clusters for nstart=1, but with nstart=100, no matter what set.seed() value is same set of clusters is the result.

I wanted to knw as to what is happening in the backend in layman terms

Comment: Oh right, well *k*-means is an iterative algorithm trying to optimise the partitioning of your objects into *k* clusters by minimising an objective function (say within cluster sums of squares). You can think of the objective function being a hilly landscape, for any point in the landscape (a single partition of *n* samples into *k* clusters) you have an altitude (the value of the objective function). Upon which, the `Kmeans()` function always wants to walk downhill. If you only tell `Kmeans()` how many clusters you want to find it starts from an random assignment of samples to clusters or...

Comment: chooses *k* samples to act as the current cluster centres. `Kmeans()` then optimises that starting configuration/partition but it may get stuck in a little valley of the objective function landscape (can only walk downhill remember); this is a **local optimum**. A much better solution may be just over a small rise, in the next valley; a **global** optimum. Hence the solution to which the algorithm converges may be dependent upon the starting configuration. `nstart` controls how many random initial configurations `Kmeans()` will try out, returning the best of the `nstart` runs.

Comment: Hence with a single run done repeatedly with different `set.seed()` you were probably finding lots of locally optimal but not globally optimal solutions to the clustering problem. That with several repeated runs with `nstart = 100` **and** different seeds you *do* get the same configuration/solution indicates to me that you have found a global, consistent solution to the clustering problem you posed. Does that help?

Comment: It abso-bloody-lutely does! makes perfect sense! 
Thanks alot @GavinSimpson for your time and effort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) is quite easy:

```
want <- c("storesize", "sales_per_sqft", "sales_per_visits", "tothhsinta")
Kmeans(stores_standard[, want], 20, iter.max = 1000, nstart = 1,
       method = c("euclidean"))
```

For 2)

```
 ## a 2-dimensional example from ?Kmeans
 x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
            matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
 colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
 cl <- Kmeans(x, 2)
```

Now look at `cl`:

```
R> str(cl)
List of 4
 $ cluster : int [1:100] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ centers : num [1:2, 1:2] 1.0245 -0.017 1.0346 0.0375
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
 $ withinss: num [1:2] 0.00847 0.22549
 $ size    : int [1:2] 50 50
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "kmeans"
```

The `cluster` component of the list contains the assigned cluster ID. These are in the same order as the samples in the input data. If you want to assign the `cluster` component as a column in the input data we'd then do:

```
R> x <- cbind(x, Cluster = cl$cluster)
R> head(x)
               x            y Cluster
[1,] -0.24251497  0.532012889       2
[2,]  0.10957740  0.225168920       2
[3,] -0.35563544 -0.428798979       2
[4,] -0.41251306  0.529953489       2
[5,] -0.61212001 -0.003443993       2
[6,]  0.04435213  0.086595025       2
```

For your data do:

```
stores_standard <- cbind(stores_standard, Cluster = kmeans_object$cluster)
```

As for 3, that doesn't appear possible with `kmeans()` in standard R nor `Kmeans()` in package **amap**.